# Python [visvis] screenshot does not work

Tags: python, screenshot

The following code to use [`visvis`](http://code.google.com/p/visvis/) results in black image no capture, why?

```
import visvis

app = visvis.use()
visvis.plot([1,2,3],[1,3,2])
visvis.screenshot('c:/captured.png')        #something is wrong with this method
```

Note that adding

```
visvis.gcf().DrawNow()
```

before capture has no effect!

Googling has been completely useless for this case, so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The figure has not had a chance to draw itself at the time that you take the screenshot. Try putting `app.ProcessEvents()` *before* taking the screenshot.

Comment: We realised that both `visvis.gcf().DrawNow()` and `app.ProcessEvents()` are required before capturing to make it working. BTW, `visvis` is very convenient for 2D and 3D, however, the screenshot even with large `sf` values is too fuzzy. Hope to see improvements in this part in the future.